# Is SSL not secure any more?

Tags: security, ssl

acording to this link https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2014-0160 is SSL not secure any more?

additional link:   http://heartbleed.com/

Comment: Why don't you read the link yourself? This isn't a programming question.

Comment: That article does not have sufficient info in my opinion thats why I wanted to post that question in here.

Comment: security.stackexchange.com is a more appropriate place, and already has a ton of good explanation.

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/55083/what-should-end-users-do-about-heartbleed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSL as a protocol is still secure. That bug exists in OpenSSL, which is one *implementation* of SSL but not the only one.

As a parallel, imagine if a bug was found in Internet Explorer. You wouldn't as a result then say "web browsing is not secure any more" - there are plenty of other web browsers, and they haven't suddenly become insecure because Internet Explorer had a bug.

Comment: In addition, all major distros rapidly released a fix for this bug. So all you need to do is update your software through your package manager (e.g. apt-get or yum) and you're fine.